# How to disable cache / touch server on every node expand in Dojo tree?

Tags: javascript, dojo, tree

I have a `JsonRest` connected to a `dijix.Tree`. The nodes are lazy loaded. that's how my tree looks like:

```
var store = new Observable(new JsonRest({
    target: "...",
    idProperty: "id",
    mayHaveChildren: function(object) {
        return object.hasChildren;
    },
    getChildren: function(object, onComplete, onError) {
        this.get(object.id).then(function(fullObject) {
            object.children = fullObject.children;
            onComplete(fullObject.children);
        }, onError);
    },
    getRoot: function(onItem, onError) {
        this.get("I1").then(onItem, onError);
    },
    getLabel: function(object) {
        return object.name;
    }
}));
```

The first time I expand a tree node, the request is being sent to the server to get the node's children.

However, this call is *cached*, so next time I expand the node, no request is being sent. I also noticed that the `getChildren` function is called only once, on first expand.

What I'd like to achieve is to disable the cache, ie. **send the request each time I expand the node**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is possible. Analyzing the code of Dojo's `Tree.js`, led me to the conclusion, that the function that is called on every node expand is

```
_expandNode: function(/*TreeNode*/ node)
```

The function contains the following code:

```
// Load data if it's not already loaded
if(!node._loadDeferred){
    // load the node
}
```

Our culprit is the `_loadDeferred` property, of course. So the question was, how to set this property for each expanded node.

I decieded to do that in `getChildren` method. First I needed to get the tree node based on item from the store and then I had to set its property to false.

1. I found out that `tree.getNodesByItem(item)` does to first part. The only thing to remember is it returns an array of nodes, so we need to take the first element:

   ```
   tree.getNodesByItem(item)[0]
   ```
2. Now it's only a matter of setting the property:

   ```
   tree.getNodesByItem(item)[0]._loadDeferred = false;
   ```

So, the **final solution** is

```
var store = new Observable(new JsonRest({
    target: "...",
    idProperty: "id",
    mayHaveChildren: function(object) {
        return object.hasChildren;
    },
    getChildren: function(object, onComplete, onError) {
        this.get(object.id).then(function(fullObject) {
            object.children = fullObject.children;
            onComplete(fullObject.children);
            tree.getNodesByItem(object)[0]._loadDeferred = false;
        }, onError);
    },
    getRoot: function(onItem, onError) {
        this.get("I1").then(onItem, onError);
    },
    getLabel: function(object) {
        return object.name;
    }
}));
```